# Update model outside of controller

Tags: angularjs

Just starting out on angular, not sure how to update a model out of a controller, or in fact if have my head around exactly what to do. I have an autocomplete field based on ion.autocomplete

**HTML**

```
  <span ng-controller="IonAutocompleteController">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Item Description</span>
            <ion-autocomplete ng-model="model"
                              item-value-key="name"
                              item-view-value-key="view"
                              items-method="getTestItems(query)"  
                              multiple-select="false"
                              placeholder="Bread, Milk, Eggs etc .."
                              items-clicked-method="itemsClicked(callback)"/>
            </span>

    <button class="button button-block button-royal" ng-click="scan()">Scan</button>


 <div class="row">
 <div class="col"><b>Item Name</b></div>
 <div class="col" ng-model="name"></div>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ion-autocomplete']);

  myApp.config(['$ionicConfigProvider', function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom')
  }]);


   myApp.controller('IonAutocompleteController', function ($scope,$http) {
                $scope.model = "";
                $scope.callbackValueModel = "";
                $scope.getTestItems = function (query) {  
                console.log(query);
                return  $http.get('http://192.168.100.100/myApp/products/' + query).
                        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log("something went wrong")    
                        });
                };
                $scope.itemsClicked = function (callback) {
                console.log(callback);
                $scope.name=callback.item.name;
                console.log(callback);
                $scope.callbackValueModel = callback;
                }
            });
```

What is happening here is the autoselect is grabbing data from a REST server and the results are place in the autocomplete. When the item is selected `callback` is returned in a json array. I want the `callback` to be place in `ng-model="name"` but it is out of the controller. Or I assume that is why it is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

your `ng-Model="name"` binds to `$scope.name` in your controller.  When data is returned from the REST call, just set `$scope.name = data`.

Comment: I don't want the data to go to $scope.name. I want the json from the callback to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate your view with autocomplete data based on what the success callback returns, not return the $http as an invocation.

```
        $http.get('http://192.168.100.100/myApp/products/' + query).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);

                    // Do whatever you need to do to data before binding it, 
                    //such as extracting a value from the JSON, etc.
                    $scope.model = data;

                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log("something went wrong")    
                    });
                };
```

Comment: `ng-model="name"` is not an input field.

Comment: @maxum - not sure I follow, I do not even have a variable named `name` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here.

1/ there is a missing `</label>`.

2/ should be using `ng-bind` NOT `ng-model` which is for inputs

Comment: There are far more problems with this than just the above. 2 is not even a problem since ion-autocomplete is technically an input field.